# How can I determine if a date is the nth List<WeekDay> in a month?

Tags: c#, .net, date

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288513/how-do-i-determine-if-a-given-date-is-nth-weekday-of-the-month), which looks for the Nth weekday in a specific month, but I want something that will look for the Nth [weekday list] in a given month. Is there an easy way to get that without looping through every day in the month?

For example, if I say I want the `3rd [Mon, Wed, Fri]` in a month, and the month starts on a Wednesday, it should return the 1st Monday (1 = Wed, 2 = Fri, 3 = Mon). If I say I want the `2nd last [Mon, Tue, Wed, Thurs]` and the last day of the month is a Sunday, it should return the previous Wednesday.

Comment: An interesting question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meh I mean you might be able to come up with something ugly and incomprehensible that is formula-based and avoids looping, but it will be ugly and incomprehensible so bug-prone and a maintenance disaster, and not at all fun to try to come up with.

Instead, just come up with what is easy to write using loops, and then *hide* the loops by using LINQ:

```
static class DateTimeExtensions {
    private static IEnumerable<DateTime> DaysOfMonth(int year, int month) {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month))
                         .Select(day => new DateTime(year, month, day));
    }

    public static DateTime NthDayOfMonthFrom(
        this HashSet<DayOfWeek> daysOfWeek,
        int year,
        int month,
        int nth
    ) {
        return
            DateTimeExtensions.DaysOfMonth(year, month)
                              .Where(
                                   date => daysOfWeek.Contains(date.DayOfWeek)
                              )
                              .Skip(nth - 1)
                              .First();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var daysOfWeek = new HashSet<DayOfWeek> {
    DayOfWeek.Monday, DayOfWeek.Wednesday, DayOfWeek.Friday
};
DateTime date = daysOfWeek.NthDayOfMonthFrom(2011, 6, 3));
Assert.Equal(date, new DateTime(2011, 6, 6));
```

Similarly, using `Reverse`, you can easily write `NthLastDayOfWeekFrom`. I'll leave it to you to come up with a better name.

Comment: Thanks for the nice and easy solution. Accepting your answer because it works nicely for my situation, but also posting the code I had put together since it doesn't use a loop. Still needs to be polished a bit though

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm accepting Jason's answer because I like his solution, however here's what I had come up with before I saw his post. I thought I'd post it because I like the idea of not looping thorough every date, especially if N is a higher value and I'd like to get a date outside the current month.

Instead of looping through all days, I fast-forwarded (or rewind if I'm going backwards) to the closest week, then looped through the next couple of days to find the Nth instance the weekdays specified.

```
public static DateTime? GetNthWeekDayInMonth(DateTime month, int nth, List<DayOfWeek> weekdays)
{
    var multiplier = (nth < 0 ? -1 : 1);
    var day = new DateTime(month.Year, month.Month, 1);

    // If we're looking backwards, start at end of month
    if (multiplier == -1) day = day.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);

    var dayCount = weekdays.Count;

    if (dayCount == 0)
        return null;

    // Fast forward (or rewind) a few days to appropriate week
    var weeks = ((nth - (1 * multiplier)) / dayCount);
    day = day.AddDays(weeks * 7);

    // Current Nth value
    var currentNth = (1 * multiplier) + (weeks * dayCount);

    // Loop through next week looking for Nth value
    for (var x = 0; x <= 7; x++)
    {
        if (weekdays.Contains(day.DayOfWeek))
        {
            if (currentNth == nth)
            {
                // Verify the nth instance is still in the current month
                if (day.Month == month.Month)
                    return day;
                else
                    return null;
            }

            currentNth += multiplier;
        }

        day = day.AddDays(multiplier);
    }

    return null;

}
```